# CTA link should be opened in new tab?

Tags: landing-page, cta

I have built an new app and also for the same I have built the landing page as well.
I have my primary CTA(Call To Action) button which is download this app on Play Store, which looks something like this.

[image]

My question is should this link to be opened in new tab or same tab ? because my purpose is met once user clicks on this CTA so there is no point in keeping the user in my landing page.

what is the best practice or is there any point in opening this link in new tab?.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question in a way, because if you don't want to keep the user on the landing page and there is no reason that it should open in a new tab then by default that's how you would design and then test if your assumption is correct. Or you could create a CTA that clearly indicates the behaviour so users know what to expect when they click on the button (e.g. put a label that say 'open in new tab' or use an icon or both). I think the UX design issue is more around meeting the expectation of the user, and whether it opens in a new tab or not is a secondary issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should it be a complex service with a lot of description on your site that a user would like to get back to, I would err on a side of opening the link in a new tab.

But since it is a quite simple app, plus the description in the Play store will probably include the same or even more info about it, **I suggest opening the link in the same tab**.

Note that **it will only be visible on a non-Android device**. On an Android device User will go to Play Store anyway, with the site kept open in a mobile browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone with the right mind would definitely want to know what makes your app special then the other apps in your category already available in the playstore. They definitely will click "about" button to know more. Even if the user clicks directly on the "Download on playstore" button. If your open the link in the same page, your lead is lost, Many people compare apps in the play store also. **I suggest you open the link in the new tab** as purely marketing strategy to keep the lead alive even after the purpose is done. If you have a thank you page or a direct download link i would suggest otherwise.